# Mobile VR headsets: hardware or software?

Tags: headset, samsung-gear-vr, samsung-galaxy-gear, daydream, daydream-vr

1. Does the Google Daydream View headset contain any electronic hardware/software components it it? If so, what are their roles?
2. Same question but for the Samsung Gear VR.
3. The Gear VR has a label on its side that reads "Powered by Oculus". What does that even mean?

I think it's safe to say the Google Cardboard has no electronic components inside the headset, right? So that's off the list.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the teardown of the two devices:

[Gear VR](https://www.slashgear.com/samsung-gear-vr-teardown-mini-18369643/) - contains circuitry for the capacitive touchpad on it, plus sensors for detecting if the user is present and USB for connecting it with the phone (presumably to send/receive the above 2 signals).

[Daydream View](https://www.electronicproducts.com/Google_Daydream_View_VR_headset-whatsinside-206.aspx) - same for the touchpad, plus NFC chips for one-touch pairing with the phone, and Bluetooth for communication with the Daydream controller.

Gear VR is [co-developed with Oculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Gear_VR) and thus bears their mark.